# Update OneToMany list after entity save in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i have relationship:

```
// In A.java class
@OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private List<B> bList;

// In B.java class
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_a")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private A a;
```

Now look this:

```
A a=new A();
// setting A

B b=new B();
// setting B
b.setA(a);

session.save(b); // this save b and a obviously
```

Now the "problem":

- a.getId() -> current new id OK
- a.getBList() -> still null...

So, why bList is not update in this case?

I tried to reload a after save, in this way:

```
A a=new A();
// setting A

B b=new B();
// setting B
b.setA(a);

session.save(b);

A loadedA=(A)session.get(A, a.getId());
```

But loadedA still have a NULL bList like a.

Naturally to avoid this problem i do in thy way:

```
A a=new A();
// setting A

B b=new B();
// setting B

List<B> bList=new ArrayList<B>();
bList.add(b);
a.setBList(bList);

session.save(a); // this save a and b
```

In this way all work good, but my question is: 
Why Id is correctly update after save operation and bList no?
I have to query db with a select statement to reload A instance correctly?

---

**UPDATE**

I have this exception

> StaleStateException: Batch update
>   returned unexpected row count from
>   update

when i try to saveOrUpdate entity a after deleting b from it.

```
// first delete old b record
Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
a.getBList().remove(b);
b.setA(null);
session.delete(b);
// session.clear(); // this would solve my problem, but is it correct??
session.getTransaction().commit();

// then insert new b record
Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
B b=new B();
a.getBList().add(b);
b.setA(a);
session.saveOrUpdate(a);   
session.getTransaction().commit(); // this throw exception
```

this two operation are not in the same method of course, are fired by gui event.

session.clear is the real solution?
Im doing (probably) wrong?

**update**

removing session.delete(b) the problem is solved again... so, what is the corretc way?
I know...im totally noob with hibernate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh... ok

```
session.refresh(a);
```

This work good... is this the solution, isn't true?

Comment: Blow, Here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive you can get a good insight about which persistence method To use when using cascading

Answer (score 6):

When working with bi-directional associations, you have to set the link on **both** sides of the association:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.getBList().add(b);
b.setA(a);

session.persist(b);
```

And actually, the common pattern is to implement defensive link management methods like this:

```
public class A {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

    protected List<B> getListB() {
        return bList;
    }

    protected void setListB(List bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    public void addBToBs(B b) {
        bList.add(b);
        b.setA(this);
    }

    //...
}
```

And the code becomes:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.addBToBs(b);

session.persist(b);
```

This is discussed in the Hibernate Tutorial:

- [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir)

Comment: @blow: Please post this as a new question, this is really a different topic.

Comment: Thank you for advice, my new question si here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077278/hibernate-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update