# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, session, transactions

I have the following relationship:

```
// In A.java class
@OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private List<B> bList;

// In B.java class
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_a")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private A a;
```

I get this exception:

```
StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update
```

When I try to `saveOrUpdate` entity a after deleting b from it.

```
// first delete old b record
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
a.getBList().remove(b);
b.setA(null);
session.delete(b);
// session.clear(); // this would solve my problem, but is it correct??
session.getTransaction().commit();

// then insert new b record
Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
B b=new B();
a.getBList().add(b);
b.setA(a);
session.saveOrUpdate(a);   
session.getTransaction().commit(); // this throw exception
```

These two operation are not in the same method of course, are fired by gui event.

Is `session.clear` the real solution? Am I (probably) doing wrong?

Removing `session.delete(b)` solves the "problem"... so, what is the correct way?

Comment: what seems strange is the @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE) on the @ManyToOne side (or more exactly having a cascade on both side). Is the one on the @ManyToOne side needed ? if not, i would try without it.